# Check if Videos are corrupted automatically

Tags: video, automation, video-encoding, file-corruption

I have 100 videos and I would like to check if they are all fully downloaded and not cut at a certain point, due to the internet breakout.

Is there a way for this to be done automatically and for the program to delete those corrupted files once found?

Answer (score 0):

[This powershell script](https://gist.github.com/Desani/129be27da7d735d7c75192ec1aa96c65) can scan all your videos, flag the ones which have issues and (optionally) try to repair them. It essentially uses existing capabilities found within ffmpeg.

The ideal flags for you seem to be `-AutoRepair -RemoveOriginal -RemoveRepaired` which attempts to repair the files that are found to have an issue. It will then delete repaired files that don't repair properly and it will delete the original files of successfully repaired files.